# How to append a large number of rows to a Google Sheet without going over the API Quota

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm writing a python program that takes data from a website and sorts it into different worksheets in a Google Sheet. The program works when appending and deleting a smaller amount of rows but when I try to insert or delete a larger amount of rows I hit the google api quota limit.

From what I can gather I believe the solution would be to use the spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate() method because from what I gathered it sends all the requests at once then once they're verified as valid requests for the specific worksheet they are all executed at once. Unfortunately, there's no gspread function that calls this method, and I'm currently lost trying to use the raw api.

This is how I'm appending my data

```py
sheet = vt.sheet1
........
with open('objectbuffer.csv', encoding='utf-8') as bfile:
        reader = csv.reader(bfile, delimiter=',')
        #gets every worksheet in the spreadsheet
        wkshts = vt.worksheets()
        #each row in the csv is evaluated for 
        #and is copied into any corresponding worksheet one at a time
        for row in reader:
            kwsFound = 0
            hasUploaded = False
            appendRow = [row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]
            #iterates through every dynamically created worksheet in the spreadsheet
            for sheets in wkshts:
                #if the title of the sheet is found anywhere within Column "E" 
                #then 1 is added to the number of keywords found
                if sheets.title in row[4]:
                    kwsFound += 1
                    kwSheet = sheets
            #if only one keyword (title of a worksheet) is found ANYWHERE in the row
            #then that row is copied to the worksheet with the name found
            if kwsFound == 1:
                kwSheet.append_row(appendRow,"USER_ENTERED")
                hasUploaded = True
            #if no keyword is found/ more than 1 is found
            #the row is copied to the conflicts worksheet (which is constant)
            if hasUploaded == False:
                conflicts.append_row(appendRow,"USER_ENTERED")
            #every row is always copied to the main worksheet
            sheet.append_row(appendRow,"USER_ENTERED")
```

the kwsFound/kwsSheet is what's sorting the data into the separate worksheets. Currently, the gspread append_row function is what I'm using to append data 1 at a time which is what is putting me over the api limit.

*Bonus Question*

This is how I'm deleting duplicate rows in my program. Since the delete requests are sent 1 at a time, this is also making the program go over the api quota

```py
allVal = sheet.get_all_values()
    rowTot = len(sheet.get_all_values())
    standard = ""
    counter = 0
    dcounter = 0
    deleteRows = []
    while counter<rowTot:
        if allVal[counter] == standard:
            deleteRows.append(counter)
        else:
            standard = allVal[counter]
        counter+=1

    while  dcounter < len(deleteRows) :
        sheet.delete_row(deleteRows[dcounter]-dcounter)
        sleep(.5)
        dcounter+=1
```

Help making this into a batchUpdate would be appreciated

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of the csv that's generated from scraping my venmo profile. http://www.filedropper.com/csvexample Though I edited it to remove personal information. Here's an example of the output I want to go into google sheets http://www.filedropper.com/gsheetsoutputexample, with all the transactions on the main sheet, but if the title of one of the secondary worksheets shows up in the description (5th column of the csv) of a transaction a copy of that transaction data is also placed in that respective worksheet. If 2 or more worksheet titles show up in the description of a transaction (or none) a copy of that transaction is then sent to the conflicts worksheet. If google sheets quotas were unlimited then my code would function in the way described without the worry of interruption.

**EDIT 2:**

1.) What I want to do is check the values of column "E" and if the title of one of the worksheets is a substring of the value of column "E" the program appends the row to the specified worksheet. So in this case values of "food", "food!", and "I love food" would all be appended to the food worksheet.

2.) The worksheet names are not constant. The program I'm building is meant to be used by my friends, so I made it so that you add named worksheets to the spreadsheets through a gui so they can make their own categories to filter their data. Let me know if you have other questions or if I didn't clarify well enough

**EDIT 3:**

Added comments to the code above

Comment: If you are still looking for the solution, can I ask you about your question? 1. About importing CSV to Spreadsheet, do you want to import whole CSV data to the Spreadsheet? 2. About deleting rows, do you want to delete rows when the column "A" of the row of the sheet is empty? 3. Do you want to achieve this using gspread?

Comment: 1.  For the csv file, in the main spreadsheet the whole file is imported, but the data from the csv is also being sorted into secondary worksheets. (For example, i'm processing my payments using venmo. So if the word food is in the description, it goes into the food worksheet, if the word gas is in the description is goes in the gas worksheet etc. But I have all of my payments in the 1st worksheet).

Comment: 2. When my program runs, it scrapes the info up until a certain date so when I append the data there can be some overlap. The way I get around this is the transaction by date then by name to get all duplicate entries next to eachother. Then I find the index of all of the duplicate rows and delete them. I have to subtract "dcounter" from the index because everytime I delete a row the index of the duplicate row decreases by 1 because the spreadsheet updates

Comment: 3. I'd like to use gspread if possible

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I thought that I recommend to update your question. By this, users can see your updated question. And also, when you provide a sample CSV file and the result Spreadsheet you want, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question and the additional information. I have 2 questions. 1. In your shared XLSX file (this original file is Google Spreadsheet.), there are 4 sheets which are `Conflicts`, `gas`, `rent` and `food`. In the shared CSV file, you want to check the values of the column "E", and you want to put the row to the sheet when the value is the same with the sheet name. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 2. For example, the sheet name of `food` has the values of `food!` and `food` at the column "E". The each sheet has already been prepared, and new sheet is not inserted by the CSV data. Namely, the sheet names are always constant. Is my understanding correct? If it's so, the declared sheet names can be used.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic of `in this case values of "food", "food!", and "I love food" would all be appended to the food worksheet.` under the condition that the sheet name is not constant. When I could understand it, I would like to think of about the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. By the way, when you put `@username` to the comment, the user can receive the notification that you commented to `username`. By this, the user can know your comment.

Comment: @Tanaike I commented my code above, I'm hoping that makes the problem easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand the logic and the vision, I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So that you do not have to wait very long, here is the [Google Sheets API Doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)  Get acquainted with it and I'll work, in the mean-time, on creating a solution for your specific situation.

Doing this with gspread, see [doc](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=append_row#models)

**Try something like this:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#This dict represents the request body for batchUpdate(body)
thisDict = {
  "requests": [
    {
      #we append update commands to a list and then place that list here.  Next we send thisDict as the body of a batchupdate.
    }
  ],
  "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": bool, #todo set this to bool value
  "responseRanges": [
    string #todo set this is string range
  ],
  "responseIncludeGridData": bool #todo set this to bool value
}

#to contain our request objects
List = []

with open('objectbuffer.csv', encoding='utf-8') as bfile:
        reader = csv.reader(bfile, delimiter=',')
        wkshts = vt.worksheets()
        for row in reader:
            kwsFound = 0
            hasUploaded = False
            appendRow = [row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]
            for sheets in wkshts:
                if sheets.title in row[4]:
                    kwsFound += 1
                    kwSheet = sheets
            if kwsFound == 1:
                List.append("kwSheet.append_row(appendRow,'USER_ENTERED')") #append command to list
                hasUploaded = True
            if hasUploaded == False:
                List.append("conflicts.append_row(appendRow,'USER_ENTERED')") #append command to list
            List.append("sheet.append_row(appendRow,'USER_ENTERED')") #append command to list

thisDict["requests"] = List #set requests equal to the list of commands

spreadsheets.batchUpdate(thisDict) #send the request body with a list of command to execute.
```

Comment: @Arvind Sundar You'll have to make the necessary adjustments, but try this section section of code I posted.  The idea is that you append your api-requests to a list, then that list is added to a body-dict which is passed into spreadsheets.batchupdate(body).

Comment: @ArvindSundar note, this spreadsheets.batchupdate(body) is a function of gspread.